# Converting Win32::OLE::Variant to perl variable?

Tags: perl, win32ole

When I extract text from an excel file it comes as `Win32::OLE::Variant=SCALAR(0x1214f94)`. How do I convert this to a Perl variable? When I try to use the value function is just prints `@data = @{$dataHash{$header}};`

```
my ($refs,$rows,$header) = &extract;

my %dataHash = %{$refs};
print "Keys:",keys %dataHash,"\n";
my @headers =  @{$header};

my @test = @{$dataHash{'Date'}};

foreach my $scalar (@test){
    print $scalar;
}

foreach my $header (@headers){
    print "Checking Header: $header\n";

    @data = @{$dataHash{$header}};

    print $data;
    foreach my $scalar (@data){
        print FH "$scalar\n";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

All I needed to do was enter `use Win32::OLE::Variant` and `Win32::OLE::Variant=SCALAR(0x1214f94)` became a readable answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, when you get a value such as `SCALAR(0x1214f94)`, you are printing a reference/address, not a value. You can dereference by adding a dollar sign in front of the variable:

```
$a = \$b;
$b = 1;
print $a;   # prints something like SCALAR(0x1214f94)
print $$a;  # prints 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, what you are getting is [Win32::OLE::Variant](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aOLE%3a%3aVariant) object, that is often returned from OLE calls when more complex type than text is needed. See methods listed in linked page and choose appropriate to get perl representation.

For instance, when you have a date in the Variant object, you can get it as string like this:

```
my $string = $date->Date("yyyy-MM-dd");
```